# String format a double to a maximum number of character in java

Tags: java, format, double

As stated in the title, I would like to write a double in a string with a maximum number of character, in java.

Well actually to an exact number of character, but I can wrap it in a `String.format("%Xs", ...)` with given X to fill missing character.

Note that there are many questions related to this on SO and internet, but I couldn't find the exact same as mine for java.

What I think of would be to write

- the full double if it fits: for max character n=10, 123.4567 is good
- round decimal and keep the integer part if it fits: for n=10, 123456.789654 would format to 123456.79
- use exponential otherwise: for n=10, 123456789123.321654 would format to 1.23457e11

=> Is there a practical tool to do that or something equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

That is what I have for now, not perfect but I spend enough time on it already.

The idea is that `Double.toString` is doing exactly what I want but for a fixed length (maybe someone knows how to configure that length?). So I use it and remove decimal when necessary

```
/** write a double to a string of exact given length (but for some extreme cases) */
public static String doubleToString(double x, int length) {
    String str = Double.toString(x);
    if(str.length() <= length){
        return org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.repeat(" ", length - str.length()) + str;

    } else if(str.contains("E")){
        String[] split = str.split("E");
        String num = split[0];
        String exp = split[1];
        return removeDecimal(num, length - exp.length()-1) + 'E' + exp;
    } else {
        return removeDecimal(str, length);
    }
}

// remove trailing decimal of a double as string such as xxx.yyyy
private static String removeDecimal(String doubleStr, int length){
    int dotIndex = doubleStr.indexOf('.');
    return doubleStr.substring(0, Math.max(dotIndex+1, length));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at BigDecimal (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) I use new DecimalFormat("0.00") if I want to ensure that the two decimal places are always shown, e.g. 1000.5 will display as 1000.50.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy any of the OP's requirements.

Comment: I've seen DecimalFormat but could reach my goal with it (but maybe I missed some features?)